# How to automatically add curly braces to all entries on JabRef?

Tags: latex, bibtex

When I download a .bib item from IEEEExplore, the paper title gets formatted in lowercase even if original title is not capitalized - in order to keep original formatting, I have to manually add curly brackets around the title. How do I set up JabRef to add curly braces to all the library entries so to keep the title capitalized?

Comment: You could disable the automatic lowering of the case https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10776 .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a known JabRef missing feature, see here:

https://discourse.jabref.org/t/add-around-capital-letters-automatically/222

To cleanup existing entries by adding braces around capitals, one could hope to use `Quality > Cleanup Entries` and then some field formatters. However, the current [field formatters](https://docs.jabref.org/finding-sorting-and-cleaning-entries/saveactions) contain "Unprotect terms" and not the opposite.

I there there is a reason for JabRef not to automatically protect all capitals it encounters, which is that it might be desirable not to force capitalization everywhere, in order to respect conventions from specific citation styles. Protection then should be used mostly for "protected terms" like abbreviations, etc.

Jabref does provide this feature: `Options > Preferences > Protected terms files`. You can add new files if needed.

Of course, if the IEEE entry had curly braces and JabRef removes them, then I think that should count as a bug.